# How to execute non sql commands in python using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am new to python. Could someone help me to figure out how to execute  following commands using cx_Oracle in python?

1. Spool C:\drop_tables.sql
2. SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;' FROM user_tables;
3. Spool off
4. @C:\drop_tables.sql

I know I can use cursor.execute() for 2nd command but for other non sql commands specially 1 & 3 I am not getting any clue.

Appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks,
Aravi

Comment: Why do you need to use `SPOOL` at all?  Can't you just read the table names from the cursor into a list and then run a `DROP TABLE` statement for each table in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I achieved what I need by following way

cur.execute("SELECT table_name FROM user_tables")

result = cur.fetchall()

for row in result:

cur.execute('DROP TABLE ' + row[0] + ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS')*

Thanks much Luke for your idea.